# Jhipster nginx 'login/oauth2/code' 404 error

Tags: angular, nginx, jhipster, keycloak

I'm having an error on Keycloak OIDC when separating angular and BE jhipster. My angular static files is deployed into nginx and had configured proxy pass to link to backend, all REST API connected no problem. My app also can open keycloak sign-in page.
The problem is after sign in, I getting /login/oauth2/code/oid/ 404 error.

By the way, when I deploy the same app (without code changes) in one bootable JAR, I can log in successfully.

My nginx conf settings:

```
server {
  rewrite_log   on;
  
  listen        81;
  
  server_name   keycloak.demo.local;
  
  charset       utf-8;
  
    location ~* ^/dbdevfe/api(.*) {
        proxy_set_header        content-type "application/json";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/dbdevfe/api$1;
    }
    location ~* ^/dbdevfe/management(.*) {
        proxy_set_header        content-type "application/json";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/dbdevfe/management$1;
    }
    location ~* ^/dbdevfe/swagger-resources(.*) {
        proxy_set_header        content-type "application/json";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/dbdevfe/swagger-resources$1;
    }        
    location ~* ^/dbdevfe/v2/api-docs(.*) {
        proxy_set_header        content-type "application/json";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/dbdevfe/v2/api-docs$1;
    }
    location ~* ^/dbdevfe/auth(.*) {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/dbdevfe/auth$1;
    }
    location ~* ^/dbdevfe/oauth2(.*) {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/dbdevfe/oauth2$1;
    }
    location ~* ^/dbdevbe/login(.*) {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/dbdevfe/login$1;
    }

    location /dbdevfe/ {
        
        proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    
        root "html/myapp_fe_link";
        
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    
    access_log logs/access_81.log;
    error_log logs/error_81.log debug;
}
```

Please advise what to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause, ie typo mistake and at the `location ~* ^/myapp/login(.*)` block need add `proxy_redirect`, something to like this:

```
location ~* ^/dbdevfe/login/oauth2(.*) {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:7444/dbdevfe/login/oauth2$1;
    proxy_redirect ~^/(.*) $scheme://$http_host:$server_port/dbdevfe/login/oauth2$1;
}
```

Anyways, after fixing the typo mistake, I still get `404 https://mydomain/login?error`

Any samples how to build the login error page?